# Searching for a string in a vector?

Tags: c++

How do you search through a vector a particular string?  And what would that search return?

I set up the following with name being a user input for search.

```
find(user_list.begin(), user_list.end(), name)
```

I am not sure how to implement this into a bool function as I do not know what value find would return.

Function is

```
bool BBoard::user_exists(const string &name, const string &pass) const{}
```

and I'm getting a lot of errors right now about how it can't compare.

Comment: Hm, that's what [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is for.

Comment: _"I do not know what value find would return"_ - can be easily solved by referencing the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Comment: std::find returns iterator : std::vector<std::string>::iterator, then if ( res_itr != user_list.end() ) { std::cout << *res_itr; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` function returns an iterator that points to the first entry in your `user_list` that matches. You do not post a lot of code but in case your code looks like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string> user_list;
```

Then you can use `find` as follows:

```
std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = find(user_list.begin(),
    user_list.end(), name)
if (i == user_list.end()) {
    // Not found
} else {
    // Found, *i is your string
}
```